# How to find out the scope of a spring managed bean

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to ascertain whether a bean is a prototype bean or not?

I'm hoping for a method on one of the variants of application Context like getScope or getBeanMetaData...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can "ask" the `BeanFactory` for the `BeanDefintion`, it contains the scope

```
 @Autowired
 ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;
 ...

 applicationContext.getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinition("beanName").getScope()
```

(`getBeanFactory()` is defined at `ConfigurableApplicationContext` which is an interface that is implemented by every concrete ApplicationContext except `StubWebApplicationContext`)

Comment: _(...) is implemented by every (...)_ – Not quite. Better use `ConfigurableApplicationContext` (without `Web`) because it is implemented by more concrete classes and also provides the necessary method.

Comment: @oberlies: you are right. I modified my answer: use `ConfigurableApplicationContext`  instead of `ConfigurableWebApplicationContext`